# Problem with creating a stack with cloud formation ("Property Type cannot be empty.")

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, aws-cloudformation, amazon-elb

So, I got this problem currently, but don't make much sence, cause I had already add the type on **`LoadBalancerListener`**...
I have tested before just the **`Load Balancer`** and the **`Target Group`**, and then they worked well, but when I add the **`Listener`**, the stack get an error. Here is the code:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: Template for load balancer

Resources: 
  DayOne:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer
    Properties:
      Scheme: internet-facing
      SecurityGroups:
        - sg-055ea833725644075
      Subnets:
        - subnet-0d7b9bf57973e6b78
        - subnet-0186890795288d48a
  LoadBalancerListener:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener
    Properties:
      DefaultActions:
        - Type: forward
        - TargetGroupArn: !Ref TargetGroup
      LoadBalancerArn: !Ref DayOne
      Port: 80
      Protocol: "HTTP"
  TargetGroup:
    DependsOn: "DayOne"
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup
    Properties: 
      TargetType: "instance"
      Name: "DayOneTarget"
      Port: 80
      Protocol: "HTTP"
      VpcId: "vpc-0f98d22c9291e3c0c"
      HealthyThresholdCount: 2
      HealthCheckTimeoutSeconds: 10
      HealthCheckIntervalSeconds: 30
```

Here is the problem:

[image]

Comment: for debugging purposes, can you remove TargetGroup resource and try

Comment: I think your main issue is under Default Actions. Instead of having a `-` for both Type and TargetGroupArn, you should only have one for type. This way they will be grouped together. You are getting the error since the second one, TargetGroupArn, is missing the required type field since its being treated as a second entry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As my comment, your issue is that your list for DefaultActions is misconfigured. You need to remove the second `-` so that your action is considered one action. When you added the second one, it is treating the `TargetGroupArn` separately from the `Type` and causes it to search for a second action.

The error message may seem misleading, but it is actually telling you that you are missing the `Type` field for your default action. Since `Type` is a required field and you have more than one action, each one needs to have it included.

What it should look like:

```
  LoadBalancerListener:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener
    Properties:
      DefaultActions:
        - Type: forward
          TargetGroupArn: !Ref TargetGroup
      LoadBalancerArn: !Ref DayOne
      Port: 80
      Protocol: "HTTP"
```